# How do I package Kivy apps for iOS?

Tags: python, ios, kivy, publish, packaging

I created an app called [Paint Maker Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pranav.pooruli.pmp) with [`Kivy`](https://www.kivy.org) and Python code and now it's on the Google Play Store. Some of my friends with iPhones want to try the app. But they can't get it from the Apple App Store. So I looked up [package for ios kivy](https://www.google.com/search?q=package%20for%20ios%20kivy) and the best answer I could find was [this](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-ios.html). But the instructions are only for people using macOS. I'm using Linux. I did try following the instructions, but I got an error while trying to install Cython. So what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely cant package without using OSX. There is a work around though. It can be tricky but I have done this to package apps for OSX itself using pyinstaller.

You are going to need to install virtualbox. Then you might have to do some research on how to install OSX in virtualbox. OSX is not supported by virtualbox. So installation can be complicated. It has been 3 years since I did this but I researched hackentosh. In some of the instructions I have read you have to have access to a actual mac so you can do some bash magic and patch the OSX installer. There is a prepackaged yosemite somewhere im sure you can download. There are also tutorials you can follow that might be more updated than the info Im giving you now.

Hope that helps. and good luck.

Comment: Can I package a Kivy app for iOS using macOS Snow Leopard?

Comment: I got an iMac with macOS X Snow Leopard installed yesterday. Then, I upgraded it to High Sierra. Will I be able to package my app for iOS on High Sierra?

Comment: @Pyzard, Not really sure. I was using pyinstaller to package back in the day and I was packaging wxPython. I was able to use snow leopard and yosemite. One advantage to using an older OS might be your app having backward compatibility with older IOS apple app versions.

That's if you aren't sacrificing your programs functionality by using outdated version of python?. Luckily you should probably be able to use whatever version of python you need using python-venv. You might have to brew that? I haven't used mac in ages.